# array with all my loops inside

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

i have this wordpress loop and i want to build a loop  with all the variables...my problem my  `$array_data` only stores the last loop and not all... how can i store all the loops in my  `$array_data` array ?

```
  foreach($adicionados as $post) :

$nome = simple_fields_values('pname1');
$im = simple_fields_values('ftotop');
$cp=$adicionados ;
$imatop = $im; 
$data=get_sub_field('wallet_data');
$evento=get_sub_field('wallet_evento');
$obs=get_sub_field('wallet_obs');  
$numeros_horas = get_sub_field('Wallet_n_horas');
$valor_horas = get_sub_field('wallet_valorh');
$evento = get_sub_field('wallet_evento');
$horarios = get_sub_field('wallet_horario');
$props=get_sub_field('wallet_props');
$total_parcial = $valor_horas * $numeros_horas."€";
$ii = wp_get_attachment_image($imatop[0]);
$array_valores['promotora'] []=  get_the_ID(); 
$array_valores['valor'][]=$total_parcial;
$nomeid=get_the_ID($nome);



$array_data = array(

  'foto' => $im,
  'data' => $data, 
  'nome' => $nome, 
  'evento' => $evento,
  'horario' => $horario, 
  'numero_horas' => $numero_horas, 
  'valor_horas' => $valor_horas,
  'valor_parcial' => $total_parcial, 
  'obs' => $obs
  );
```

Comment: `$array_data[] = array(`

Comment: nice to hear it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing the last loop data because every time it loops it's storing different data. Which is similar to the following code:

```
$foo = 'one';
$foo = 'two'; // replaces 'one' with 'two'
$foo = 'three'; // replaces 'two' with 'three'

echo $foo; // outputs only 'three'
```

You need  a two dimensional array here. An array of arrays.

Traditionally, you would make an index `$i` and store each loop's data with `array_data[$i]`, exactly the essence of `for( $i = 0; $i < count($adicionados); $i++)`.

But as mentioned in the comment, `$array_data[]` does that for you (although not as fast).